# How to find all the binary string of length 9, having 4 ones and rest zeroes and hamming distance of 4 (if we consider any two strings)

Tags: algorithm, hamming-distance

eg. I want all the strings like
1. 110011000000 & 110000110000
2. 110011000000 & 110000001100
etc.
Also what is the general algorithm to find these strings

Comment: We don't write code for you. You write some code and we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: This is a similar question for Hamming distance 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451090/permutations-of-binary-number-by-swapping-two-bits-not-lexicographically/36466454#36466454

Comment: This is even more similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680863/number-of-different-binary-string-with-k-flips/37733467#37733467